# Do we need "trouble with paper" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the [trouble-with-paper](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trouble-with-paper) tag. 
It is a meta tag and I think it not a useful tag for for filtering or searching and 
I think questions should stand alone and contain enough information to make sense independent of papers they may use as context. Coming from someone reading a paper doesn't add much useful information about the content of the question. Would one care if a question is coming from reading a paper or from a discussion or just thinking about some problem?
Do we really need this tag?

Comment: think the site has really great potential for reviewing hard sections/jumps of difficult papers (have various items on that) & there seems a large/inexhaustible supply but votes/conventions seem to have pushed against it eg the rigid preprint policy fixed in place yrs ago =( ... also dislike the se-wide mod tendency of micromanaging/pushing against collective tag [folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) and killing new/creative/useful tags before they even get off ground as surrogate for managing/restricting/constraining scope...

Comment: The tag seems of low utility, for me personally.  It seems to have been first used by domotorp in a reasonable way (I don't have access to any earlier now-deleted questions that may have introduced it prior to this one).  Whatever the merits or demerits of the tag, I am not sure that my own preferences should necessarily be authoritative -- tags are a community feature.

Comment: @vzn What does the tag actually achieve? If you were having trouble with a paper about widgets, you'd search for questions about widgets, not for questions asked by other people who were having trouble with the paper they were reading.

Comment: I've (finally) removed the trouble-with-paper tag.